# Google Scripts Send email not working

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

New to google scripts, and I can't get the code below functioning. It is triggered by onEdit, it should cycle through every row of data, check column B for either a "*Bypass*" or "*Declined*" value, and send an email to that row's email address (colum G), UNLESS column A indicates it was already sent. Then, after all that, update column A with a "Sent" value so that no one gets double sent.

This is what I have, where am I going wrong?

```
function sendEmail() { 
    // return all data in active spreadsheet
    var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
    for (i in values.length) { //iterate over each row

        var data = values[i][1];     // get value of column 2 (aka B) for this row - this is your conditional cell for emailing

        var check = values[i][0];    // Previously sent emails

        var fname = values[i][2];    // get first name of applicant

        var emailAddress = values[i][6];      // get email address from column G

        var subject = "Thanks for Applying with Echo Hospitality";

        var message = fname + ", <p>After careful review, we are going to move forward with other candidates at this time. Thanks for applying, we appreciate the effort that went into it.<p>Regards,<p>The Echo Hospitality Team";

        // if data cell equals Bypass or Declined AND check is not Sent, send email, then update the check column
        if (data == "Bypass" || "Declined" && check != "Sent") ;{
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "hr@echo-staffing.com", subject, message);
            check.setValue("Sent");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: besides the obvious error, what about the actual logic? is it *if data is Bypass, or (data is Declined and check not sent), then send* .... or is it ... *if (data is bypass or declined) and check not sent, then send* ?

Comment: The logic should be: if (data is bypass or declined) and check not sent, then send

Comment: so that probably means the logic needs to be: if (data == "Bypass" && check != "Sent" || data == "Declined" && check != "Sent")

Comment: @JaromandaX what do mean by "the obvious error?"

Comment: The error that was addressed in the answer already - the thing that wasn't addressed was if/where you needed `()`